# Set ASP.Net GridView column to Button field programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm generating the columns of a gridview in code which is working fine (I have `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` set on the page), so I don't have any columns defined in the html markup.

I would like to make one of the columns a ButtonField, so I can use a RowCommand handler in the code - is there a way to make a column a ButtonField programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ButtonField programmatic adding:

```
var buttonField = new ButtonField
                      {
                          ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
                          Text = "My button",
                          CommandName = "DoSomething",
                      };
Grid.Columns.Add(buttonField);
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="RowCommandHandler"></asp:GridView>
```

Handler:

```
protected void RowCommandHandler(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DoSomething")
    {
        // place code here
    }
}
```